# Count all possible unions in a collection of sets

Tags: combinatorics, sets

Say we have a collections of sets $\mathcal X = \{X_1, \dots, X_n\}$ (not necessarily disjoint), and we want to count the number of possible unions of sets in $\mathcal X$, i.e. the size of $\{\bigcup_{Y \in \mathcal Y} Y \,|\, \mathcal Y \subseteq \mathcal X \}$.

Is there a name for this problem?
What are the fastest algorithms to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14277/computing-the-union-closure).
It is called the union closure and the complexity appears to be the same as computing the number of maximal independent sets in a bipartite graph.